# How to set volume for push notification using external sound in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, volume

I am using Push Notification in my app. I am able to play the Mp3 sound for push . Now i want to set the volume for Mp3. I don't know how to set the volume for push. here is my code for push Sound.

```
Thread t = new Thread()
    {
            public void run()
            {
                MediaPlayer player = null;

                player = MediaPlayer.create(GCMIntentService.this,R.raw.traffic);
                player.start();

                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(player.getDuration()+100);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {

                }
            }
        };
    t.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this . Here is my solution code .

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            //am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
            switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
                Log.i("MyApp", "Silent mode");
                am.setVolumn(0, 0);
                break;
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
                Log.i("MyApp", "Vibrate mode");
                am.setVolumn(0, 0);
                break;
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
                Log.i("MyApp", "Normal mode");
                am.setVolumn(0, 10);
                break;
            }
```